# ARM assembly: How do I change the code to ask number input then print it out and then ask character input and print it out?

Tags: assembly, input, arm, printf, scanf

```
@ Use these commands to assemble, link, run and debug this program:
    
    @    as -o student_inputC.o student_inputC.s
    
    @    gcc -o student_inputC student_inputC.o
    
    @    ./student_inputC 
    
    @    gdb --args ./student_inputC 
    
    
        .equ READERROR, 0 @Used to check for scanf read error. 
    
        .global main @ Have to use main because of C library uses. 
    
        main:
    
        prompt:
    
    
    
 @ Ask the user to enter a number.
     
          ldr r0, =strInputPrompt 
    
 @ Put the address of my string into the first parameter
      
         bl  printf              
    
 @ Call the C printf to display input prompt. 
    
 @ Ask the user to enter a character.
    
        ldr r0, =charInputPrompt
       
        bl printf
    
    
    
        get_input:
    
    
    
 @ Set up r0 with the address of input pattern.
    
 @ scanf puts the input value at the address stored in r1. We are going
 @ to use the address for our declared variable in the data section - intInput. 
 @ After the call to scanf the input is at the address pointed to by r1 which 
 @ in this case will be intInput. 
    
      
        ldr r0, =numInputPattern @ Setup to read in one number.
       
        ldr r1, =intInput        @ load r1 with the address of where the
                                
 @ input value will be stored. 
    
        bl  scanf                @ scan the keyboard.
    
        cmp r0, #READERROR       @ Check for a read error.
    
        beq readerror            @ If there was a read error go handle it. 
    
        ldr r1, =intInput        @ Have to reload r1 because it gets wiped out.
     
        ldr r1, [r1]             @ Read the contents of intInput and store in r1 so that
    
                                
    
        ldr r0, =charInputPattern @ Setup to read in one number.
    
        ldr r1, =charInput        @ load r1 with the address of where the
    
                                  
    
        bl  scanf                @ scan the keyboard.
    
        cmp r0, #READERROR       @ Check for a read error.
    
        beq readerror            @ If there was a read error go handle it.
     
        ldr r1, =charInput        @ Have to reload r1 because it gets wiped out.
     
        ldr r1, [r1]             @ Read the contents of intInput and store in r1 so that it 
    
    
    
  @ Print the input out as a number.
    
  @ r1 contains the value input to keyboard. 
    
        ldr r0, =strOutputNum
    
        bl  printf
    
        b   myexit
    
        ldr r0, =strOutputChar
    
        bl  printf
    
        b   myexit @ leave the code. 
    
    
    
         readerror:
    
    
    
    @ Got a read error from the scanf routine. Clear out the input buffer then
    @ branch back for the user to enter a value. 
    
    @ Since an invalid entry was made we now have to clear out the input buffer by
    @ reading with this format %[^\n] which will read the buffer until the user 
    @ presses the CR. 
    
         ldr r0, =strInputPattern
         ldr r1, =strInputError   @ Put address into r1 for read.
         bl scanf                 @ scan the keyboard.
    @  Not going to do anything with the input. This just cleans up the input buffer.  
    @  The input buffer should now be clear so get another input.
    
         b prompt
    
         myexit:
    
    @ End of my code. Force the exit and return control to OS
    
         mov r7, #0x01 @ SVC call to exit
         svc 0         @ Make the system call. 
    
        .data
    
    @ Declare the strings and data needed
    
         .balign 4
    
         strInputPrompt: .asciz "Input the number: \n"
    
         .balign 4
    
         strOutputNum: .asciz "The number value is: %d \n"
    
         .balign 4
    
         charInputPrompt: .asciz "Input the character: \n"
    
        .balign 4
    
         strOutputChar: .asciz "The character is: %c \n" 
    
    @ Format pattern for scanf call.
    
        .balign 4
    
         numInputPattern: .asciz "%d"  @ integer format for read. 
    
        .balign 4
    
         strInputPattern: .asciz "%[^\n]" @ Used to clear the input buffer for invalid input. 
    
        .balign 4
    
        strInputError: .skip 100*4  @ User to clear the input buffer for invalid input. 
    
        .balign 4
    
        intInput: .word 0   @ Location used to store the user input.
    
        .balign 4
    
        charInputPattern: .asciz "%c"  @ integer format for read. 
     
        .balign 4
    
        charInput: .word 0   @ Location used to store the user input 
    
    @ Let the assembler know these are the C library functions. 
    
        .global printf
    
    @  To use printf:
    @     r0 - Contains the starting address of the string to be printed. The string
    @          must conform to the C coding standards.
    @     r1 - If the string contains an output parameter i.e., %d, %c, etc. register
    @          r1 must contain the value to be printed. 
    @ When the call returns registers: r0, r1, r2, r3 and r12 are changed. 
    
            .global scanf
    
    @  To use scanf:
    @      r0 - Contains the address of the input format string used to read the user
    @           input value. In this example it is numInputPattern.  
    @      r1 - Must contain the address where the input value is going to be stored.
    @           In this example memory location intInput declared in the .data section
    @           is being used.  
    @ When the call returns registers: r0, r1, r2, r3 and r12 are changed.
    @ Important Notes about scanf:
    @   If the user entered an input that does NOT conform to the input pattern, 
    @   then register r0 will contain a 0. If it is a valid format
    @   then r0 will contain a 1. The input buffer will NOT be cleared of the invalid
    @   input so that needs to be cleared out before attempting anything else.
    @
    @ Additional notes about scanf and the input patterns:
    @    1. If the pattern is %s or %c it is not possible for the user input to generate
    @       and error code. Anything that can be typed by the user on the keyboard
    @       will be accepted by these two input patterns. 
    @    2. If the pattern is %d and the user input 12.123 scanf will accept the 12 as
    @       valid input and leave the .123 in the input buffer. 
    @    3. If the pattern is "%c" any white space characters are left in the input
    @       buffer. In most cases user entered carrage return remains in the input buffer
    @       and if you do another scanf with "%c" the carrage return will be returned. 
    @       To ignore these "white" characters use " $c" as the input pattern. This will
    @       ignore any of these non-printing characters the user may have entered.
    @

    @ End of code and end of file. Leave a blank line after this.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run the program, It ask "Input number" and Input character at the same time. Then I input number and it prints out the number, but the wrong number and I cannot input character

Comment: That is an error description.  Now, what is your question?

Comment: How do I change the code to ask number input then print it out and then ask character input and print it out?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is pretty simple. Let's look at the code carefully:

```
LDR r0,=StringInputPrompt
BL printf
LDR r0,=charInputPrompt
BL printf
```

Ignoring branch predictors and out-of-order execution for now, assembly is executed in the order written, from top to bottom. You're loading the string that says "Input the number" into R0, then printing it, and then the string that says "Input the character" then printing it. You've printed the strings that ask for input but haven't taken any actual input until after you've printed both prompts.

Next, we'll look at the `getInput` section:

```
   get_input:
        ldr r0, =numInputPattern  @ Setup to read in one number.
        ldr r1, =intInput         @ load r1 with the address of where the

        bl  scanf                 @ scan the keyboard
        cmp r0, #READERROR        @ Check for a read error.
        beq readerror             @ If there was a read error go handle it. 
        ldr r1, =intInput         @ Have to reload r1 because it gets wiped out.
        ldr r1, [r1]              @                
    
        ldr r0, =charInputPattern @ Setup to read in one number.
        ldr r1, =charInput        @ The problem is here! (added by me)                 
        bl  scanf                 @ scan the keyboard.
        cmp r0, #READERROR        @ Check for a read error.
        beq readerror             @ If there was a read error go handle it.
        ldr r1, =charInput        @ Have to reload r1 because it gets wiped out.
        ldr r1, [r1]
```

Once again, you've taken the input correctly, but then you've overwritten r1 with =charInput. The important thing to understand about assembly is the difference between a register and permanent memory. Take a look at this:

```
LDR R0,=intInput
LDR R0,=charInput
```

Having these two back to back is the same as not having the first one at all, i.e.

```
LDR R0,=charInput
```

because each register can contain only one value at a time and when you load a new value the old is discarded.

The rest of your code seems like it's working, so a simple rearranging of your code should fix it:

```
        main:
 @ Ask the user to enter a number.
        ldr r0, =strInputPrompt 
 @ Put the address of my string into the first parameter
        bl  printf              
 @ Set up r0 with the address of input pattern.
        ldr r0, =numInputPattern @ Setup to read in one number.
        ldr r1, =intInput        @ load r1 with the address of where the
        bl  scanf                @ scan the keyboard.
        cmp r0, #READERROR       @ Check for a read error.
        beq readerror            @ If there was a read error go handle it. 
        ldr r1, =intInput        @ Have to reload r1 because it gets wiped out.
        ldr r1, [r1]             
@ Print the input out as a number.
        ldr r0, =strOutputNum
        bl  printf
        

 @ Ask the user to enter a character.
    
        ldr r0, =charInputPrompt
        bl printf

        ldr r0, =charInputPattern @ Setup to read in one number.
        ldr r1, =charInput        @ load r1 with the address of where the
        bl  scanf                 @ scan the keyboard.
        cmp r0, #READERROR        @ Check for a read error.
        beq readerror             @ If there was a read error go handle it.
        ldr r1, =charInput        @ Have to reload r1 because it gets wiped out.
        ldr r1, [r1]            
  
        ldr r0, =strOutputChar
        bl  printf
    
        b   myexit @ leave the code.
```

**TL;DR:** The order of instructions in assembly matters. A lot.